# Selecting and Replacing Non ASCII Characters

Tags: php, utf-8, str-replace, replace

I have written a simple function to replace Non ASCII Turkish characters.

```
function url_cevir($yazi) {
        $yazi = trim($yazi);

        $eski = array('ü','Ü','ö','Ö','ş','Ş','ç','Ç','ı','İ','ğ','Ğ',' ');
        $yeni = array('%C3%BC','%C3%9C','%C3%B6','%C3%96','%C5%9F','%C5%9E','%C3%A7','%C3%87','%C4%B1','%C4%B0','%C4%9F','%C4%9E','%20');


        return str_replace($eski,$yeni,$yazi);
    }
```

It precisely works when i define it in the page where i call it. But it only replaces spaces when i include it with an external page.

All code are here and there is no other code to contaminate these

from external page:

```
<?php

include('functions/array_and_string_fns.php');


echo url_cevir('ısı geçişi');
?>
```

If i use it with `echo url_cevir('ısı geçişi');` it prints `ısı%20geçişi`
If i use `echo ('ısı geçişi');` it prints `ısı geçişi` as we expected.
So i think problem is coming from function url_cevir
And I think i am missing something very simple. Othervise it is an very interesting problem.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  If you don't want your function to encode spaces as `%20`, remove that part from the arrays in your function.

Comment: It has to replace all $eski= characters with $yeni= characters. But it only replaces spaces when i include this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put literal characters into a source file, the encoding of the actual source file becomes significant.

I think your source files have different encodings. Check the settings on your text editor.